# Laravel 5.1 CentOs7 deployement Not Found The requested URL was not found on this server

Tags: php, mysql, git, centos

I am trying to deploy my laravel project, I have installed Apache, MySQL, PHP, composer and laravel. I have pulled in my project via git and ran composer install, php artisan migrate --seed. When I go to my site I see the homepage of my app great! When I try to go to an other page let's say /auth/register I get the error The requested URL was not found on this server.

Here are my permissions on my files:

```
drwxr-xr-x 12 root   root     4096 Nov 22 16:33 ..
drwxr-x--- 10 apache apache   4096 Nov 22 16:33 app
-rwxr-x---  1 apache apache   1646 Nov 22 16:33 artisan
-rwxr-x---  1 apache apache    320 Nov 22 16:33 behat.yml
drwxr-x---  3 apache apache   4096 Nov 22 16:33 bootstrap
-rwxr-x---  1 apache apache   1665 Nov 22 16:33 composer.json
-rwxr-x---  1 apache apache 143064 Nov 22 16:41 composer.lock
drwxr-x---  2 apache apache   4096 Nov 22 16:33 config
drwxr-x---  5 apache apache   4096 Nov 22 16:33 database  
drwxr-x---  3 apache apache   4096 Nov 22 16:33 features
drwxr-x---  8 apache apache   4096 Nov 22 16:33 .git
-rwxr-x---  1 apache apache    135 Nov 22 16:33 .gitignore
-rwxr-x---  1 apache apache    503 Nov 22 16:33 gulpfile.js
-rwxr-x---  1 apache apache    159 Nov 22 16:33 package.json
-rwxr-x---  1 apache apache     87 Nov 22 16:33 phpspec.yml
-rwxr-x---  1 apache apache    899 Nov 22 16:33 phpunit.xml
drwxr-x---  5 apache apache   4096 Nov 22 16:33 public
-rwxr-x---  1 apache apache   1928 Nov 22 16:33 README.md
drwxr-x---  5 apache apache   4096 Nov 22 16:33 resources
-rwxr-x---  1 apache apache    567 Nov 22 16:33 server.php
drwxr-x---  5 apache apache   4096 Nov 22 16:33 storage
drwxr-x---  2 apache apache   4096 Nov 22 16:33 tests
-rwxr-x---  1 apache apache    494 Nov 22 16:33 Vagrantfile
drwxr-x--- 39 apache apache   4096 Nov 22 16:42 vendor
```

My virtual host file:

```
<Directory "/home/spark/public">
 Require all granted
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName myurl
 DocumentRoot "/home/spark/public"
 ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/spark-error"
 CustomLog "/var/log/httpd/spark-customlog" Common
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: try chmod 755 folder `storage` enable `mode_rewrite`

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it by adding:
Allowoverride All

My virtual host file looks like this now

```
<Directory "/home/spark/public">
 Require all granted
 Allowoverride All
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName myurl
 DocumentRoot "/home/spark/public"
 ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/spark-error"
 CustomLog "/var/log/httpd/spark-customlog" Common
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName myurl
  DocumentRoot "/home/spark/public"
  <Directory "/home/spark/public">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
  ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/spark-error"
  CustomLog "/var/log/httpd/spark-customlog" Common
</VirtualHost>
```

and `sudo restart apache2`

Comment: Thanks for your input but I've added my answer on how I fixed it